# seq create list quarters R

Tags: r, sequence

I want to use the list of all quarters between two quarters, set in variables as characters.
But I get an error.

```
timeMin <- "2015Q1"
dissemPeriod <- "2022Q1"
list(seq(as.yearqtr(timeMin),as.yearqtr(dissemPeriod),by="quarter"))
```

```
Error in del/by : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Comment: Replace `by = "quarter"` with `by = 1/4` .  Omit `list` as it is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure `seq` accepts quarter format, so you convert to date format and convert back to quarter:

```r
library(zoo)
timeMin <- as.Date(as.yearqtr("2015Q1"))
dissemPeriod <- as.Date(as.yearqtr("2022Q1"))
as.yearqtr(seq(timeMin, dissemPeriod, by="quarter"))

# [1] "2015 Q1" "2015 Q2" "2015 Q3" "2015 Q4" "2016 Q1" "2016 Q2" "2016 Q3" "2016 Q4" "2017 Q1" "2017 Q2"
# [11] "2017 Q3" "2017 Q4" "2018 Q1" "2018 Q2" "2018 Q3" "2018 Q4" "2019 Q1" "2019 Q2" "2019 Q3" "2019 Q4"
# [21] "2020 Q1" "2020 Q2" "2020 Q3" "2020 Q4" "2021 Q1" "2021 Q2" "2021 Q3" "2021 Q4" "2022 Q1"
```

Comment: Since `yearqtr` represents a year and quarter internally as year + fraction where fraction is 0, 1/4, 1/2, 3/4 for the 4 quarters this can be shortened to `seq(as.yearqtr(2015), as.yearqtr(2022), 1/4)` or even shorter  `as.yearqtr(seq(2015, 2022, 1/4))`